# DB2 Encrypt Function - Insert Encrypt data

Tags: encryption, insert, db2

I am trying to insert data into table from application
statement required "insert into table1 (memberid) values (encrypt('1111','abcdef'))".
however application is preparing as
insert into table1 (memberid) values ('encrypt('1111','abcdef')') and Rows are getting inserted.

while  select decrypt_char(memberid,'abcdef') from table1
getting SQL20146N - The Decryption function failed. The data is not encrypted.

Comment: Show us the code. It seems your statement has issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error if you have made mistakes in your code or column declaration.

You should avoid using `ENCRYPT()` and `DECRYPT_CHAR()` because they are considered insecure , and are deprecated so might be removed from a future release of Db2. Instead use Db2 native encryption or underlying file system encryption.

Below is a worked example for your case, on Db2-LUW:

```
create table table1(memberid varchar(64) for bit data)


insert into table1 (memberid) values (encrypt('1111','abcdef'))

select hex(memberid) from table1

1                                                                                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0828D8FFB804AFD51CFBD754BD9D234F                                                                                                




select decrypt_char(memberid, 'abcdef') from table1

1                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------
1111
```